# jQuery - Get numeric position/index of spcific <li> in an unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple unordered list and would like to find the numeric index/position of a specific element.

e.g:

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li id="id_a">Content</li>
    <li id="id_b">Content</li>
    <li id="id_c">Content</li>
    <li id="id_d">Content</li>
    <li id="id_e">Content</li>
</ul>
```

**Pseudo code:**

```
$('ul#mylist').getNumericIndexOf('id_c'); // 2
$('ul#mylist').getNumericIndexOf('id_a'); // 0
$('ul#mylist').getNumericIndexOf('id_e'); // 4
```

Any input is much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ra003xhf/)

```
$("#id_c").index();
```

Comment: @n00b No problems, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                    console.log($("#id_b").index("li"));
            });
</script>
```

Comment: What if the OP has more than one `ul` on the page with `li`'s inside it? Your index is contextual to the document itself **not** within the current list